# Changing license of a product to reduce restriction

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, licensing

Suppose that i licensed my product with a license, but then i wanted to remove some restriction on the license to give customer more freedom. I thought to do this by changing the license such that the new license allows everything that previous license allowed, does not add new restriction, and the new license allowed some thing that the previous license prohibit. Is it possible to change license under this condition? if not, is there any other way to achieve similar effect ?

Comment: If you are the owner of the work, you are free to change the licence under which it is issued. Note the text of the licences themselves are often copyrighted, so you should either wholly replace the licence with one that makes more sense, or ensure any modifications to the licence text itself comply with the conditions of the licence.

Answer (score 0):

The copyright owner may release, or re-release, a work under any license s/he pleases, at any time. The new license may have more, or fewer, or jut different restrictions, permissions, and conditions.

However, a user who obtained the work under the earlier license may continue to use it under the terms of that license, unless the original license  contained an end-date or other applicable termination provision. But the owner may cease distributing it under the original license if s/he so chooses.

While it is true that the texts  of most standard open-source or permissove licenses are protected by copyright, and might not be directly modifiable, the ideas of a license are not ever protected by copyright, and one can write a different license based on an existing one.  In practice, if a copyright owner uses a  modified version of a standard license, but does not use **name** of that license, and does not distribute the modified version in any way other than attaching it to the owner's own work, it is very unlikely that any legal action would be brought.